# Send Image data Between two HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a camera web app where currently I capture and show the captured image in my index.html. This code works well.

Now, I want to share the captured image data and show it in another HTML i.e part1.html.

But, when I put the same Base 64 incoded data as img src inside part1.html, I am getting an empty image. Why is that happening? And how can I resolve it? Below are my code.

### index.html

```
<html lang=”en”>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Name of the app -->
    <title>Camera App</title>

    <!-- Link to main style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <main id="camera">

        <!-- Camera sensor -->
        <canvas id="camera--sensor"></canvas>

        <!-- Camera view -->
        <video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline></video>

        <!-- Camera output -->
        <img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">

        <!-- Camera trigger -->
        <button id="camera--trigger">Take a picture</button>

    </main>

    <!-- Reference to your JavaScript file -->
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
</body>
```

### app.js

```
// Set constraints for the video stream
var constraints = { video: { facingMode: "user" }, audio: false };
var track = null;

// Define constants
const cameraView = document.querySelector("#camera--view"),
cameraOutput = document.querySelector("#camera--output"),
cameraSensor = document.querySelector("#camera--sensor"),
cameraTrigger = document.querySelector("#camera--trigger");

// Access the device camera and stream to cameraView
function cameraStart() {
navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(stream) {
        track = stream.getTracks()[0];
        cameraView.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Oops. Something is broken.", error);
    });
}

// Take a picture when cameraTrigger is tapped
cameraTrigger.onclick = function() {
cameraSensor.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
cameraSensor.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
cameraSensor.getContext("2d").drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);
//cameraOutput.src = cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/webp");
var cameraValue = cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/png");
cameraOutput.src = cameraValue;
console.log(cameraValue)
var queryString = "?para1=" + cameraValue;
//window.location.href = "part1.html" + queryString;
cameraOutput.classList.add("taken");
// track.stop();
};

// Start the video stream when the window loads
window.addEventListener("load", cameraStart, false);
```

### part1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Name of the app -->
    <title>Captured Image</title>

    <!-- Link to main style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<h4>These are the data from index.html.</h4>
<img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">
<script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
cameraOutput = document.querySelector("#camera--output")
var foo = getParameterByName('para1');
console.log(foo);
cameraOutput.src = foo;
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```